# Python Nested For Loops Augmentation Possible?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, for-loop, nested

Given a single string

```
abcd
```

I need to generate the following output:

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'b', 'bc', 'bcd', 'c', 'cd', 'd']
```

I have put the following code together in Python 3.8 and it works, but is very clunky and inefficient:

```
text = 'abcd'
final = [text[y:i+1] for i in range(len(text)) for y in range(len(text)) if len(text[y:i+1]) > 0]
print(sorted(final))
```

Is there a more elegant or efficient way to achieve the required output, without using nested for loops?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
s = "abcd"

out = [s[i:j] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
["a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "b", "bc", "bcd", "c", "cd", "d"]
```

---

EDIT: With one loop:

```py
s = "abcd"
n = (len(s) * (len(s) + 1)) // 2

out, cnt1, cnt2 = [], 0, 0
for _ in range(n):
    cnt1 += 1
    out.append(s[cnt2:cnt1])
    if cnt1 > len(s) - 1:
        cnt2 += 1
        cnt1 = cnt2

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
["a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "b", "bc", "bcd", "c", "cd", "d"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to achieve the desired output without using nest loops?